# htaccess regex ignore query string in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using click guardian on my website which adds a query string to the end of my URL, but it is effecting any page after www.example.co.uk/page/ and does not display dynamic content.

**For example**

example.co.uk/page
(page is dynamic)

Pulls dynamic content fine when it has the query string, but the below URL does not pull dynamic content when the query string is in the URL

example.co.uk/page/example-page
(example-page is a physical page)

The full query string that is added is

```
?gclid=CjwKCAjwqNnqBRATEiwAkHm2BF-zsUvEuQ20fJ_4IV4fxfSJFC2BbmW7CERm1WAJ_-iiJDUxOQUYrhoCfVwQAvD_BwE
```

I have ignored the query string in page using php which works fine but trying to ignore it on example-page does not work.

I have been trying to find a way in htaccess to ignore the query string that is added and still leaves it in the url, as click guardian need it to be present to track clicks.

**Edit**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/(.*)\.php\s+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page.php?get=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?\s+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2.php?get=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/([^/]+)/\s+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/([^/]+)/?\s+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page.php?get=%1 [L,QSA]


#ErrorDocument 404 /page.php
```

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules in your .htaccess file? Can you show the content of it?

Comment: Please see edit